# Subtracting value of the record with group_id IS NOT NULL from group_id IS NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to subtract "count" field of records with "group_id" IS NOT NULL from the same field of records with group_id IS NULL when it is both have the same date

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test` (`date`, `group_id`, `count`) VALUES
('2021-05-15', NULL, 3),
('2021-05-15', 1, 2),
('2021-05-15', 2, 1);
```

Basically, it should subtract 2 and 1 from 3 and update 3 to 0.
So I made it with INNER JOIN:

```
UPDATE test AS t1
INNER JOIN test t2 
SET t2.count = t2.count - t1.count
WHERE 
    t1.group_id IS NOT NULL AND 
    t2.group_id IS NULL AND 
    t1.date = t2.date;
```

It works with 2 records, but with 3, like in my example, it ignores the second record with group_id=2. So the result is count = 3 becomes 1 instead of 0.

How to properly fix it? Add another INNER JOIN or I should use a different approach? (just it may be more than 2 group_id IS NOT NULL records)

P.S. There is only 1 record with group_id IS NULL for each date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to aggregate before joining:

```
UPDATE test t1 JOIN
       (SELECT date, SUM(count) as cnt
        FROM test t2 
        WHERE group_id IS NULL
        GROUP BY date
       ) t2
       ON t1.date = t2.date
    SET t1.count = t1.count - t2.count
WHERE t1.group_id IS NULL ;
```